# dialog box not creating in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have used this coding to creating a dialog box which can be moved and resizable and Could not see a dialog box as an output,please help and is there any libraries missing in it?

**HTML**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"> </script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                                                      
</script>

<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
</body>
```

**This is my Jquery function**

```
<script>
$(function()
{
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>
```

Comment: why you include 2 jquery?

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: do you have css code? also you forgot to close the </div> tag

Comment: dont have any CSS code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download and created a seperate folders and added these and atlast got the output

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Thanks all for the answers..took a lot of time to figure this out..

Answer (score 3):

I'm recommending you to use this as your [reference](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Notice this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>
```

or download the jQuery library from [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com/)

and change it to..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Im using the same link as a reference and could not get the output

Comment: can you see in the console if all the lib are loading?

Comment: do you have this? <script src="jquery.min.js"></script> also try to check the location/directory of the jquery

Comment: Yes I have and rechecked again

Comment: Yes <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 2):

You are loading jQuery library twice from two CDNs. Remove this line.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

Always remember to include jQuery library before any jQuery plugin is included. Also avoid multiple jQuery references.

Comment: Yeah I have removed that still I could not get any dialogbox

Comment: I believe you have not added any jQuery UI CSS for this. See my sample here http://jsfiddle.net/9Rh8R/

Comment: follow http://jsfiddle.net/9Rh8R/show/ this to see the same Fiddle as a single page, not inside jsfiddle.

Comment: It works in Jsfiddle and can you please elaborate which Jquery UI CSS should be added

Comment: The one I used was picked from http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryUI192.ashx. There are other CDNs like Google that you can use. There is jQuery UI ThemeRoller so that you can build your own theme also.

Comment: Could you please edit my script coding and post the corrected coding so can check if that works and thanks for the effort

Comment: See the fiddle please. Its working with your code, with some changes I made.

Answer (score 1):

Please add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />" media="screen" />
```

**updated**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: everything's seems to be okay.so frustating that cannot get this output.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#divAssetUrl").dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               title: 'Add Assest Url',
               minWidth: 500,
               minHeight:500
           });
<script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```